# Spacer for non-drive side dropout

Tags: rear-wheel, hanger, derailleur-hanger

My bike has a hanger like this:

[image]

Since the nut acts as a spacer between the end of the dropout and the hub, it's quite hard to center the wheel. What kind of spacer/accessory can be mounted on the other side so that you can just pull the wheel and it would be aligned when it hits the spacer and the hanger? The dropouts don't have adjustment screws.

Comment: I'm not aware of a specific spacer, but you could try fitting a second one on the NDS but flip the hanger to point upward.  They're cheap at about $4 each.  Problem is there's no bolthole in the frame.   So you could just use the insert and that bolt, and fit a washer whereever required.

Comment: I've seen such spacers occasionally, but they aren't generic, and they would be hard to adjust.

Comment: Unless you can do it yourself, your LBS may drill and tap an M3 hole at the rear of the left drop-out and fit a single adjustment screw which I believe is the best solution.

Answer (score 4):

There are spacers that are sort of in the vein of what you describe. They look like this:

[image: dropout spacers]

However, these are intended to be used as a matched set and aren't adjustable, so using just one of them probably wouldn't just do what you're wanting here. You could probaby file one down to make it do that, however.

Another thing to bear in mind here is that it's actually very common, especially in the bike boom era, for manufacturers to use the horizontal dropouts of their frames to give themselves room to be a little sloppy with the symmetry of the left and right chainstay/dropout assemblies. As long as the paths of the axle slots are parallel, having the start and end points be off by a few mm doesn't matter much. In other words there are a lot of horizontal dropout bikes where if, say, you pulled the axle all the way back in the dropouts on each side, the wheel would be off-center in the frame, and where using spacers like the pictured ones wouldn't work unless you nudged one ahead of the other the right amount.

Comment: Googling for "dropout spacer" gives a lot of examples of such spacers. They tend to be very dropout/frame specific. As an example, I used [Surly's Monkey nuts](https://surlybikes.com/parts/wheels/monkey_nuts) with my Surly frame, even though they were not officially compatible with that frame. As a result, only one spacer could be installed as is - another one would have required filing down to make it a half millimeter or so thinner. Having even one spacer installed helped me however, as it set a reference point for the rear axle in its new position, so that I could tighten the second end.